# Android Studio HttpURLConnection not posting data

Tags: android

I am trying to post data to my `localhost` by using `AsyncTask` which is accessible on `10.0.3.2:8787` by Genymotion and `127.0.0.1:8787` by Localhost. But, it seems to not post anything. Below is my code;

```
private class LocationUpdateTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String _url = "http://10.0.3.2:8787/user_locations/save";
        HttpURLConnection httpClient = null;
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                String urlParameters = params[i];
                System.out.println(urlParameters); // Prints fine here.
                URL url = new URL(_url);
                httpClient = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpClient.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpClient.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                httpClient.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                httpClient.setUseCaches(false);
                httpClient.setDoInput(true);
                httpClient.setDoOutput(true);
                //Send request
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpClient.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (httpClient != null) {
                httpClient.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class LocationUpdaterListener implements LocationListener
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //String text = "Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + "\nLong: " + location.getLongitude();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        HashMap<String, String> postDataParams=new HashMap<String, String>();
        postDataParams.put("fuid", profileId);
        postDataParams.put("lat", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
        postDataParams.put("lng", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
        postDataParams.put("alt", String.valueOf(location.getAltitude()));
        postDataParams.put("br", String.valueOf(location.getBearing()));
        postDataParams.put("acc", String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()));

        String urlParameters = null;

        try {
            urlParameters = "fuid=" + URLEncoder.encode(postDataParams.get("fuid"), "UTF-8")+
                    "&lat="+URLEncoder.encode(postDataParams.get("lat"), "UTF-8")+
                    "&lng="+URLEncoder.encode(postDataParams.get("lng"), "UTF-8")+
                    "&alt="+URLEncoder.encode(postDataParams.get("alt"), "UTF-8")+
                    "&br="+URLEncoder.encode(postDataParams.get("br"), "UTF-8")+
                    "&acc="+URLEncoder.encode(postDataParams.get("acc"), "UTF-8");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (urlParameters != null){
                new LocationUpdateTask().execute(urlParameters);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
}
```

No exception thrown whatsoever. If I do it normally by accessing through browser and pass the parameter, it works just fine. So, I assume something must be wrong with my code.

So, which is wrong in my code? Or anything I should try to see why this is not working?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: The server is on Windows? Try to access from your device/emulator web browser. Check your firewall.

Comment: @dieter_h It's on Ubuntu 14.04. I tried with emulator's browser and ubuntu's browser by direct link with parameters and they both work just fine.

Comment: You don't use `urlParameters` in `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: Can you try calling wr.flush() on the OutputStreamWriter to force it to flush its contents? -- Edit: so that would be: wr.write(val); wr.flush(); wr.close();

Comment: @Guardanis I've tried with and without `wr.flush` as in `OutputStream, DataOutputStream, and OutputStreamWriter`. Still no lucks.

Comment: Use Volley. That's far more easier!
http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

Comment: @RuchiraRandana Thanks, I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally got it working. I don't know why but It looks like I have to let `HttpURLConnection` to call `getInputStream` at the very last of the code, like;

```
InputStream is = httpClient.getInputStream();
```

or

```
// getResponseCode also calls getInputStream.
int responseCode = httpClient.getResponseCode();
```

So, finally my code looks like this,

```
private class LocationUpdateTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String _url = "http://10.0.3.2:8787/user_locations/save";
        HttpURLConnection httpClient = null;
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                String urlParameters = params[i];
                URL url = new URL(_url);
                httpClient = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpClient.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpClient.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                httpClient.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                httpClient.setUseCaches(false);
                httpClient.setDoInput(true);
                httpClient.setDoOutput(true);
                //Send request
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpClient.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                //InputStream is = httpClient.getInputStream();
                int responseCode = httpClient.getResponseCode();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e("TAG", "Exception", e.fillInStackTrace());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (httpClient != null) {
                httpClient.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```